# Render a table after submitting a form from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and unable to find the resource that will help me with what I am trying to achieve.

Basically I have a view that has a form to collect some data, on hitting submit, I want the controller to process the data (fetch some more information) and render a 1 row table.

Here's my form (view)

```
<form action="track/do_track" name="track" id="track-form" class="ajax"  method="post">
  
    <div class="table-bar">
      <input type="button" value="Submit" name="Submit" class="uiButton unitExt" id="confirm_submit_button" onclick="submit()"/>
      <div class="fclear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="table" class="table">
      <div class="line thead">
        <div class="unit th" style="width:160px"><span class="scan-icon-white">ID</span></div>
        <div class="unit th" style="width:175px">
          A/B
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class ="line tr" >
        <%= content_tag :div, :class=>"unit td" do %>
            <%= text_field_tag("shipment_id","",:id=>"id", :class=>"shipment-text padding5", :autofocus => true)%>
        <% end %>

        <%= content_tag :div, :class=>"unit td" do %>
            <select class="mh-ph fk-select-box" name="a-b" id="mf-ph">
              <option id="a" value="A">MotherHub</option>
              <option id="b" value="B">PickupHub</option>
            </select>
        <% end %>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In routes.rb

```
  match "/track/track_page" => "track#track_page"
  match "/track/do_track" => "track#do_track"
```

On hitting submit I am invoking `do_track` in `track_controller`

```
def do_track
  # some processing
  # render a table in the same view 
  end

  def track_page
    render
  end
```

How can I achieve rendering just a new table on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

You will need some Javascript for that (unless you want to re-render the whole page again).

I suggest you check the [Working with Javascript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) documentation for some helpful examples.

The [Server Side Concerns](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns) part is the most basic and simple approach for the case you want.